# SailsJS - Mongo find with where or condition Association (one to one)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a model:

```
module.exports = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {

    friend1: {
      model: "User", //Logged in User
      required: true
    },
    friend2: {
      model: "User", //Profile Viewing User to whom I can send friend request
      required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: "int",
      defaultsTo: "0"
    }
  }
};
```

Now I am trying to check if any user is my friend or not with below written filter, seems it is not working!

```
Friend.find().where({
    or: [
        {
            friend1: user_id,
            friend2: fried_id
        },
        {
            friend1: fried_id,
            friend2: user_id
        }
    ]
}).exec(function findCB(err, Friend) {
    if(err) throw err;
    next(Friend);
});
```

Can anyone figure me out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

There is somehow a related closed issue for that [**How to use Search Modifier “OR” in Sails.js using Waterline Adapter for Mongo**](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/116), depending on the version you're using. As a workaround, I can only suggest you try using the **[`native()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)** which accesses a raw Mongo collection instance representing the specified model, allowing you to perform raw Mongo queries:

```
var criteria = { 
    "$or": [
        { "friend1": user_id, "friend2": friend_id },
        { "friend1": friend_id, "friend2": user_id }
    ]
};

// Grab an instance of the mongo-driver
Friend.native(function(err, collection) {        
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    // Execute any query that works with the mongo js driver
    collection.find(criteria).toArray(function (err, friendObj) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(friendObj);
    });
});
```

Comment: np seems it has an issue yet, when I use above example I got an error something like: 

mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec'

Comment: I even also tried with below toArray callback seems this one also not working and returning me []:

Friend.native(function(err, collection) {        
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    collection.find(criteria).toArray(function (err, friendObj) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(friendObj);
        next(friendObj);
    });
});

Comment: What version of Sails are you using? When it was working, how did you run the script?

Comment: 1. I am using v0.11.2
2. It was working when I used a undefined user_id
3. command line: sails lift